# ruby on rails log file to big -> remove params from it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, parameters, truncate

i made a distribuited real-time system in RoR, it's compose by 2 machine.

PC A:
take images from a Camera and send these to the second PC. So this machine send every second an http request with the image in the params.
PC B - the server:
save the image in a database.

My problem is that the log file become too big because log even the params string. 
How can i set the logger to truncate the params? or simply remove it?

sorry for my bad english..... i hope that someone can help me.
Bye
Davide Lentini.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the log level to be less verbose.

See the [rails guide on debugging](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels).

So for your entire application (in development), add this to config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.log_level = :warn # In any environment initializer, or
```

Or, to change the logging level directly in your application:

```
Rails.logger.level = 0 # at any time
```

Comment: I think changing the `log_level` will suppress other info.

Answer (score 26):

To specifically remove certain params from the logs you can set the `config.filter_parameters` in `application.rb` like this:

```
config.filter_parameters += [:parameter_name]
```

This will replace the value of the filtered parameter with "[FILTERED]".

Comment: Adding quick reference for those who find this answer in the future: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/FilterParameters.html

Comment: this is for which version on rails?

Comment: As far as I know this has been around for the last six years. It's still in the current edgerails guides. I think this must have been around at least since rails 2.1.0.

Comment: You can also specify lambda, as seen from Oli's link.